# TYPO3 9: Default htaccess-file not working as include in vhost of apache webserver

Tags: apache, .htaccess, typo3, typo3-9.x

we are currently trying to load the default htaccess file of TYPO3 v9 into our apache servers via include instead of putting it into the document roots. In version 8 this worked without problems with the default htaccess. If we take the template file from the

```
typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess
```

it works in the document root but not as include in the vhost. We get a lot of "internal redirects with ..." and eventually the webserver crashes because there are too many redirects. Has anyone ever had the problem?

We include with

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/xxx/">
Require all granted
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

Include /etc/httpd/root-htaccess
AllowOverride all </Directory>
```

And here some of the log-file:

```
...
[Fri Feb 22 13:05:17.4446xxx 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 27130] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58029] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [xxx.xxx.local/sid#55869c6xxx540][rid#55869c886380/initial] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/xxx/] internal redirect with /var/www/vhosts/xxx/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
        [Fri Feb 22 13:05:17.446123 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 27130] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58029] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [xxx.xxx.local/sid#55869c6xxx540][rid#55869c88bc70/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/xxx/] internal redirect with /var/www/vhosts/xxx/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
        [Fri Feb 22 13:05:17.447188 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 27130] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58029] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [xxx.xxx.local/sid#55869c6xxx540][rid#55869c892908/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/xxx/] internal redirect with /var/www/vhosts/xxx/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
        [Fri Feb 22 13:05:17.448299 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 27130] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58029] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [xxx.xxx.local/sid#55869c6xxx540][rid#55869c897968/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/xxx/] internal redirect with /var/www/vhosts/xxx/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
        [Fri Feb 22 13:05:17.449325 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 27130] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58029] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [xxx.xxx.local/sid#55869c6xxx540][rid#55869c89d108/initial/redir#4] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/xxx/] internal redirect with /var/www/vhosts/xxx/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
        [Fri Feb 22 13:05:17.450570 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 27130] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:58029] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [xxx.xxx.local/sid#55869c6xxx540][rid#55869c8a3238/initial/redir#5] [perdir /var/www/vhosts/xxx/] internal redirect with /var/www/vhosts/xxx/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
...
```

Thanks for any help or hints.

Comment: Well, what are the rules implemented in that file?

Comment: Keep in mind that rewriting rules operate on _absolute_ paths in the static host configuration while they operate on _relative_ paths in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). So unless you have implemented the rules specifically such that they work for both cases you can very well receive different results.

Comment: @arkascha that's the file https://pastecode.xyz/view/4a743e3f

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue.

just set

`Rewritebase /`

in your vhost-file in the `<directory>` part.